# Send Notification to Specific Topic in Firebase in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I'm trying to send firebase message from java code , and I have done this from the console and its working and I'm receiving Notification on My Devices , and also I have sent messages through java to specific Devices via token and its working too , and I'm having trouble sending ones to topic , I get no error and no exception from server side but nothing is received on devices.
here's the code I'm using to send Requests to firebase :

```
 String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM;   // You FCM AUTH key
    String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

    URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+authKey);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("to","/topics/all");
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("message",title);
    json.put("data", data);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());
    wr.flush();
    conn.getInputStream();
}
```

as you can see the inner object in the Json is Data with param "message" like the one provided on google docs , I've also tried replacing it with "notification" with "body" and "title" as its working for sending messages to specific devices via token but again not working for topics.
and again its not needed to mention that everything on the android side is working cause it works sending Topic Message through firebase console

UPDATE : this method is working and I have to Handle it to actually show the notification when the message is Received .

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: Hi Mahan. Are you positive that the devices you intend to send the message to is subscribed to a topic called `all`? (e.g. `subscribeToTopic("all")`)?

Comment: @AL. yea I mentioned that its working when I send message through FireBase Console and I get the notification that is send through "ALL" topic

Comment: Yeah I get that. It's just kinda hard to picture it without the code for the subscription. Is that the actual name of the topic (`ALL`)? All uppercase? or was it just to emphasize?

Comment: @ALi  no its "all" actually and I'm using "all" on both sides (server,app)

Comment: can you show your FMCurl?

Comment: @MuhibPirani "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" , as I said I'm using the same code to send notifications to specific devices via token , so nothing should be wrong with the url o the api key or anything like these

Comment: did you debug and check the onMessageReceived method in FirebaseMessagingService class?

Comment: Strange. Could you try sending the message using a simple request (sample using Postman or cURL are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=201706120740486774994)) and see if it's the same?

Comment: @MuhibPirani I did it again now and its getting called and the remote message contains my Message but shouldn't it handle it and send a simple notification , or I have to handle it my self?, thank you for reminding it

Comment: @AL. I tested it through post man and again my server too , the onMessageRecieved is called and my message is in there but the notification is not shown , I guess I have to handle it myself , but the console ones was shown automatically ... anyway thank you too !

Comment: You will have to handle those notifications as it has message and data along with it. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method is working now and have to handle it to actually show the notification when the message is received on the device .